# Drupal Override Custom Menu Template

Tags: html, drupal

I created a custom menu called "sub-top-nav" and now I'd like to override the html output. In particular I would like to add an unique class to each item like.

This is how it looks atm:

```
<div class="clear-block block block-menu" id="block-menu-menu-sub-top-nav">
    <div class="content">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="leaf first"><a title="Test 1" href="/test1">Test 1</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a title="Test 2" href="/test2">Test 2</a></li>
      <li class="leaf active-trail"><a class="active" title="Test 3" href="/test3">Test 3</a></li>
      <li class="leaf last"><a title="Test 4" href="/test4">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I'd like to change it into:

```
<div class="clear-block block block-menu" id="block-menu-menu-sub-top-nav">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="leaf test1 first"><a title="Test 1" href="/test1">Test 1</a></li>
      <li class="leaf test2"><a title="Test 2" href="/test2">Test 2</a></li>
      <li class="leaf test3 active-trail"><a class="active" title="Test 3" href="/test3">Test 3</a></li>
      <li class="leaf test4 last"><a title="Test 4" href="/test4">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This would give me more styling power.
Any idea how that works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it to work now. This piece of code might help someone else as well!
It goes into yourtheme/template.php

```
function phptemplate_menu_item($link, $has_children, $menu = '', $in_active_trail = FALSE, $extra_class = NULL) {

  $class = ($menu ? 'expanded' : ($has_children ? 'collapsed' : 'leaf'));

  if (!empty($extra_class))
    $class .= ' '. $extra_class;

  if ($in_active_trail)
    $class .= ' active-trail';

  $class .= ' ' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', strtolower(strip_tags($link)));

  return '<li class="'. $class .'">'. $link . $menu ."</li>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Drupal 7 uses theme_menu_link instead of theme_menu_item

```
<?php
function theme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: "theme_menu_link instead of theme_menu_link"? What's the point here?

Comment: Exactly. "theme_menu_link instead of theme_menu_item".

Answer (score 3):

After looking through the API I finally found an easy solution to tag the root menu with the same class (this is useful to style only the top level menus uniquely, while maintaining them dynamically friendly). Simply use the plid instead of mlid. I noticed the plid is always 0 for top level menus.

```
function theme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']['plid'];

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
        $count = 1;
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [theme_menu_item](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_menu_item/6) function in your theme's template.php to do pretty much whatever you want to those menu items, including adding classes, ID's, etc.

Comment: alright but how does it work for a custom menu? could you give me an example?