# Change the default HTML output for a menu

Tags: php, drupal

I need to customize the html output for a menu.

This is the default output:

```
<section id="block-menu-menu-header-en" class="block block-menu">
    <div class="content">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="collapsed first"><a href="/home" title="">GROUP</a></li>
            <li class="collapsed"><a href="/services" title="SERVICES">SERVICES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- /.content -->
</section> <!-- /.block -->
```

This is the output what i need:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="first"><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="space.html" title="Facilities Management, Facilities Planning and Project Management">Space</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I would like to know if this is even possible because i can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can change your theme in the `sites/all/theme` directory but why do you want to change it?

Comment: Because i recieved a complex responsive html site to integrate with drupal and would be much easyer to change the html output from drupal than css files.

Comment: I've tried in sites/all/themes but cant figure how.

Comment: [Drupal 7: Modifying menu HTML output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189307/drupal-7-modifying-menu-html-output?lq=1)