# Drupal Superfish Menu - controlling spacing per item

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-theming, superfish

I'm currently using the Danland theme for Drupal 7 and need help controlling the superfish horizontal spacing on a per item basis.

The css for the individual items is `#superfish .menu li.leaf` I'm able to control the first item in my menu by using `#superfish .menu li.first.leaf` - same way for last item.

How do I control the individual item spacing if the only css for those items is `...leaf` ?  Is the only way via javascript?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use JavaScript or [CSS (albeit not every browser will support the CSS route)](http://jsfiddle.net/7B2pT/).

But your best bet may be to use a theme override, using Drupal's `_hook` system. [The accepted answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317462/drupal-override-custom-menu-template) may be a good starting point.

Someone updated the code for Drupal 7 here: [Drupal Override Custom Menu Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317462/drupal-override-custom-menu-template/6495105#6495105).